# You don't have permission to post in a group

Tags: c#, facebook, winforms, facebook-c#-sdk

I've finished a program in C# which integrates with Facebook and posts to more than one group in a click

but I am facing a problem right now when there is a group that you don't have a permission to post to I can't complete posting to the rest

here's the post function 
I put it in other Class

```
public static bool PostImage(Frm form,string AccessToken, string Status, string ImagePath) 
{
    try
    {
        if (form.listBox2 .SelectedItems .Count  > 0)
        {
            string item;
            foreach (int i in form. listBox2.SelectedIndices)
            {
                item = form.listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
                groupid = item;

                FacebookClient fbpost = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
                var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);
                dynamic res = fbpost.Post("/" + groupid + "/photos", new
               {
                   message = Status,
                   File = new FacebookMediaStream
                   {    
                       ContentType = "image/jpg",
                       FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
                   }.SetValue(imgstream)

               });
                result = true;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a try catch block inside the loop. Then, in the catch block you log the error (or do whatever you want with it) then continue the loop:

```
foreach (int i in form. listBox2.SelectedIndices)
{
    try
    {
        item = form.listBox2.Items[i].ToString();
        groupid = item;

        FacebookClient fbpost = new FacebookClient(AccessToken);
        var imgstream = File.OpenRead(ImagePath);
        dynamic res = fbpost.Post("/" + groupid + "/photos", new
       {
           message = Status,
           File = new FacebookMediaStream
           {    
               ContentType = "image/jpg",
               FileName = Path.GetFileName(ImagePath)
           }.SetValue(imgstream)

       });
        result = true;
    }
    catch(exception excp)
    {
        //Do something with the exception
    }
}
```

Now I don't know exactly how your code works, but this should give you a rough idea.

Comment: I didn't get the answer!!!
I'll edit the question please recheck it now and give me some help